# Haskell performance when calculating min/max/sum over large list

Tags: haskell

I have been experimenting with the following Haskell code:

```
data Foo = Foo
  { fooMin :: Float
  , fooMax :: Float
  , fooSum :: Float
  } deriving Show


getLocalFoo :: [Float] -> Foo
getLocalFoo x = Foo a b c
  where
    a = minimum x
    b = maximum x
    c = sum x

getGlobalFoo :: [Foo] -> Foo
getGlobalFoo x = Foo a b c 
  where
    a = minimum $ fmap fooMin x
    b = maximum $ fmap fooMax x
    c = sum $ fmap fooSum x


main :: IO()
main = do
  let numItems = 2000
  let numLists = 100000
  putStrLn $ "numItems: " ++ show numItems
  putStrLn $ "numLists: " ++ show numLists

  -- Create an infinite list of lists of floats, x is [[Float]]
  let x = take numLists $ repeat [1.0 .. numItems] 

  -- Print two first elements of each item
  print $ take 2 (map (take 2) x)

  -- First calculate local min/max/sum for each float list 
  -- then calculate the global min/max/sum based on the results.
  print . getGlobalFoo $ fmap getLocalFoo x
```

And sequentially tested runtime when adjusting numItems and numLists:

**Low size:**

```
numItems: 4.0
numLists: 2
[[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0]]
Foo {fooMin = 1.0, fooMax = 4.0, fooSum = 20.0}

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.001s
```

**High size:**

```
numItems: 2000.0
numLists: 100000
[[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0]]
Foo {fooMin = 1.0, fooMax = 2000.0, fooSum = 1.9999036e11}

real    0m33.116s
user    0m33.005s
sys 0m0.109s
```

I have written this code in a in my opinion intuitive and naive way without consideration to performance, however I am concerned that this is far from optimal code as I may actually be folding through the lists way more times then necessary?

*Could anyone suggest a better implementation of this test?*

Comment: You are calculating three statistics of two hundred million elements in 33 seconds.  That's about twenty million elements per statistic per second.  Does that sound inefficient to you?  (You do have a massive space leak however, but that's something else.  This will help you out on that http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html)

Comment: While you may be right about this, my main purpose with the question is to understand if the code can be improved upon wrt. performance.

Comment: I would like to upvote this comment for the "You do have a massive space leak however…"

Comment: flagged for migration to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `foldl` library to run multiple folds efficiently in a single pass.  In fact, it's so good at this that you don't need to split your list into sublists.  You can just concatenate all the lists together into one giant list and fold that directly.

Here's how:

```
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Control.Foldl as L

data Foo = Foo
  { fooMin :: Maybe Float
  , fooMax :: Maybe Float
  , fooSum :: Float
  } deriving Show

foldFloats :: L.Fold Float Foo
foldFloats = Foo <$> L.minimum <*> L.maximum <*> L.sum
-- or: foldFloats = liftA3 Foo L.minimum L.maximum L.sum

main :: IO()
main = do
    let numItems = 2000
    let numLists = 100000
    putStrLn $ "numItems: " ++ show numItems
    putStrLn $ "numLists: " ++ show numLists

    -- Create an infinite list of lists of floats, x is [[Float]]
    let x = replicate numLists [1.0 .. numItems] 

    -- Print two first elements of each item
    print $ take 2 (map (take 2) x)

    print $ L.fold foldFloats (concat x)
```

The main differences from your code are:

- I use `replicate n`, which is the same thing as `take n . repeat`.  In fact, that's how `replicate` is actually defined
- I don't bother processing the sublists individually.  I just `concat` them all together and fold that in a single pass.
- I use `Maybe` for the minimum and maximum since I need to handle the case of an empty list.
- This code is faster

Here are the numbers:

```
$ time ./fold
numItems: 2000.0
numLists: 100000
[[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0]]
Foo {fooMin = Just 1.0, fooMax = Just 2000.0, fooSum = 3.435974e10}

real  0m5.796s
user  0m5.756s
sys   0m0.024s
```

`foldl` is a really small and easy to learn library.  You can learn more about it [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.0.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is a tidy solution, but the sum is different? See my original post.

Comment: What result do you get if you compile and run my example on your machine?

Comment: Same number as you get, but it is not the same as I have in my original example.

Comment: So I think the issue in this case is that floating point addition is not associative, which may be why we get different answers

Comment: I'm not following.. Which answer can you trust in this case?

Comment: Neither one!  You're actually better off using unlimited precision `Integer`s instead of `Float` if you want a precise answer.  If I replace all instances of `Float` with `Integer` (and change the `1.0` to `1`), then both programs give the exact same answer for the sum: 200100000000.

Answer (score 1):

Monoids to the rescue. All your operations - the sum, minimum and maximum - can be all expressed as monoids. For the minimum and maximum we need to wrap it into `Option` from the [semigroups](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups), because we need to represent somehow the minimum and maximum of an empty collection. (An alternative way would be to restrict ourself to non-empty collections, then we could use semigroups instead of monoids.)

Another thing we'll need is to ensure that all computations are forced during each step. For this we declare `Foo`'s instance of `NFData`, add some missing instances of the monoid types we use, and a helper function that forces values during the folding operation.

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Semigroup

-- Declare the data type so that each field is a monoid.
data Foo a = Foo
  { fooMin :: Option (Min a)
  , fooMax :: Option (Max a)
  , fooSum :: Sum a
  } deriving Show

-- Make a Monoid instance - just by combining individual fields.
instance (Ord a, Num a) => Monoid (Foo a) where
  mempty = Foo mempty mempty mempty
  mappend (Foo n1 x1 s1) (Foo n2 x2 s2) = Foo (n1 <> n2) (x1 <> x2) (s1 <> s2)

-- Add missing NFData instances
instance (NFData a) => NFData (Option a) where
  rnf (Option x) = rnf x `seq` ()
instance (NFData a) => NFData (Min a) where
  rnf (Min x) = rnf x `seq` ()
instance (NFData a) => NFData (Max a) where
  rnf (Max x) = rnf x `seq` ()
instance (NFData a) => NFData (Sum a) where
  rnf (Sum x) = rnf x `seq` ()

-- Also add an instance for Foo
instance (NFData a) => NFData (Foo a) where
  rnf (Foo n x s) = rnf n `seq` rnf x `seq` rnf s `seq` ()

-- Convert a single element into Foo.
locFoo :: a -> Foo a
locFoo x = Foo (return $ Min x) (return $ Max x) (Sum x)

-- A variant of foldMap that uses left fold and forces monoid
-- elements on the way.
foldMap' :: (F.Foldable f, Monoid m, NFData m) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
foldMap' f = F.foldl' (\m x -> (mappend $!! m) (f x)) mempty

main :: IO()
main = do
  let numItems = 2000
  let numLists = 100000
  putStrLn $ "numItems: " ++ show numItems
  putStrLn $ "numLists: " ++ show numLists

  -- Create an infinite list of lists of floats, x is [[Float]]
  let x = take numLists $ repeat [1.0 .. numItems]  :: [[Float]]

  -- Print two first elements of each item
  print $ take 2 (map (take 2) x)

  -- First calculate local min/max/sum for each float list 
  -- then calculate the global min/max/sum based on the results.
  print . foldMap' (foldMap' locFoo) $ x
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I am confused of the advantages here as my example "high size" parameters gives more then 2min runtime with this code.

Comment: @toeplitz The code isn't optimized for speed. It's advantage is that the program consumes only constant memory, not depending on the size of the list. All three results (min/max/sum) are computed together, so there is no need to retain the whole list in memory - it's constructed and consumed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a single fold is cheaper. Try running some tests with something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.List

getLocalFoo :: [Float] -> Foo
getLocalFoo [] = error "getLocalFoo: empty list"
getLocalFoo (x:xs) = foldl' f (Foo x x x) xs
  where f (Foo !min1 !max1 !sum1) y =
          Foo (min1 `min` y) (max1 `max` y) (sum1 + y)
```

and its analogous for `getGlobalFoo`.